# SQL Server global temporary table created via JDBC does not persist

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Is there any way to create a global temporary table using JDBC on SQL Server that will persist after my connection has closed?

I'm finding that if I create a global temporary table using the JTDS JDBC driver, it does not exist after my connection closes:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE ##foobar([name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)";
Statement stmt = connection.getConnection().createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

What I want is a table that is visible to everyone and will persist across connections until server restart.

Comment: Um. That's pretty well the *definition* of a global temp table - it disappears when the connection that created it is closed, and no other connections are referencing it. Perhaps what you need is a plain old permanent table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Maybe he thinks global temporary tables work the same way as in Oracle...

Comment: don't they get removed at the end of the session in Oracle as well? http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/temporary-tables.php

Comment: @hircus - my understanding is that in Oracle, they are permanently declared *structures* - their temporary nature relates to the rows that they contain. When the session closes, the rows disappear, but the table still exists.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for, tukushan? A permanent structure, with the rows isolated to each session?

Comment: My bad - you are right, this is the definition of a global temporary table. What I want is a table that is visible to everyone and will persist until server restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all all connections that have referenced them have closed (see the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

In this case what I need is a Tempdb permanent tables that is visible to everyone, and is deleted when the server is restarted:

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..foobar([name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a continuation of the original question.

Comment: I wanted a table that is visible to everyone and will persist across connections until server restart - this answer describes how to do that by creating a table in tempdb.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something that has *similar* behavior to an Oracle style temp table, using a permanent table, a view, and a logon trigger:

```sql
create table dbo._Data (
    Session int not null constraint DF__Data DEFAULT (@@SPID),
    ColumnA int not null,
    ColumnB int not null
)
go
create view dbo.Data (
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
)
with schemabinding
as
    select
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB
    from
        dbo._Data
    where
        Session = @@SPID
with check option
go
create trigger T_Data_Logon_Cleardown
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
    delete from Database.dbo.Data
go
```

You then perform all of your actions against the `dbo.Data` "table".

This has the characteristics that each session's rows are isolated, and if you disconnect and reconnect, the "table" will be empty.

What you don't get is an automated clearing of rows on transaction boundaries (if that's your preferred option - you'll have to do a manual delete). Nor is it exactly similar, since rows will remain in the table until a new session claims an old session ID (so cleanup occurs later, if at all). But from the client perspective, it may be "close enough".